# Change styles for biblatex bibliography headings in memoir

Tags: biblatex, chapters, memoir

How could I change the style for chapter bibliographies without changing how they appear in the table of contents or the style those for other unnumbered sections? Specifically, I would like them to be in `\normalsize`, `\bfseries` and small caps.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[
  refsection=chapter,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
  @article{carroll2006method,
    author={Carroll, Christopher D.},
    title={The method of endogenous gridpoints for solving dynamic stochastic optimization problems},
    journaltitle={Economics Letters},
    volume={91},
    number={3},
    pages={312 - 320},
    date={2006-06},
    doi={10.1016/j.econlet.2005.09.013},
  }

  @article{mcfadden1989method,
    title={A method of simulated moments for estimation of discrete response models without numerical integration},
    author={McFadden, Daniel},
    journaltitle={Econometrica},
    doi={10.2307/1913621},
    pages={995-1026},
    publisher={Wiley, Econometric Society},
    volume={57},
    number={5},
    date={1989-09},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents*

  \chapter{Preface}
  \section*{First section}
  \section*{Second section}

  \mainmatter
  \chapter{First chapter}
  \nocite{carroll2006method}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]

  \chapter{Second chapter}
  \nocite{mcfadden1989method}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to redefine the relevant `bibheading`:

```
\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \setsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\scshape\MakeLowercase}
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
}
```

I haven't added `\bfseries` to the definition in the full example, because the default Computer Modern font doesn't have bold small caps, and so you won't see the effect, since the small caps will be substituted. But assuming you have a font that has bold small caps you can get the format you want.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[
  refsection=chapter,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{carroll2006method,
    author={Carroll, Christopher D.},
    title={The method of endogenous gridpoints for solving dynamic stochastic optimization problems},
    journaltitle={Economics Letters},
    volume={91},
    number={3},
    pages={312 - 320},
    date={2006-06},
    doi={10.1016/j.econlet.2005.09.013},
  }

  @article{mcfadden1989method,
    title={A method of simulated moments for estimation of discrete response models without numerical integration},
    author={McFadden, Daniel},
    journaltitle={Econometrica},
    doi={10.2307/1913621},
    pages={995-1026},
    publisher={Wiley, Econometric Society},
    volume={57},
    number={5},
    date={1989-09},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \setsecheadstyle{\normalsize\scshape\MakeLowercase}
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
}

\begin{document}

  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents*

  \chapter{Preface}
  \section*{First section}
  \section*{Second section}

  \mainmatter
  \chapter{First chapter}
  \nocite{carroll2006method}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]

  \chapter{Second chapter}
  \nocite{mcfadden1989method}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of first chapter]

Comment: I hazarded to add a small edit with the missing styling. Also, I do have a font that has bold small caps :-)

Comment: @FredrikP Thanks!